# ReactJS with Express Server CORS setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

Even though many questions have asked on CORS issues, none helped me. First of all, I understand what CORS is and why it is important.

I don't want to disable CORS. I want to use it properly.

I have a ReactJS app running on `http://localhost:3000`. Also I have my backend NodeJS application running on `http://localhost:1234`.

I have enabled CORS from my NodeJS app like below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000") // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
});
```

This is how my request looks like in ReactJS app:

```
axios
    .post(this.props.endPoint, formData)
    .then(res => {
        console.log("Successfull");
        this.setState({
            loginOk: true
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

This is the login page. When I submit my request, I see the below error in browser console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1234/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

*Update*

I have discovered that REST endpoint that I was calling is completely wrong. Fixing it resolved the issue.

### Summary

If you have this setup like I described in the question, it should work without any problem. Also, I would go for alternate library that @T.J. Crowder suggested to use in side my NodeJS app.

Comment: What status *does* the `OPTIONS` (preflight) response come back with? (You may need Fiddler or similar to find out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that the subsequent routes you're chaining to with `next` don't realize they're dealing with an `OPTIONS` request (the preflight). The response to the preflight should *only* be the headers.

If so, you can fix it like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000") // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.status(200).end();
  } else {
    next()
  }
});
```

...provided that middleware is prior to others, etc.

That said, you might look at a tried-and-tested middleware rather than rolling your own. [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) seems to be popular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your first point helped me to find out that my request path that calls in ReactJS is completely wrong. Second, using `cors` library would be pretty neat. +1 again!